# elementary OS Update

Tags: release-loki, updates, apt, repositories

I just installed elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki on an iMac over the last weekend and everything went swimmingly well.

This AM when I try `sudo apt-get update`,

I get this message:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

---

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't xenial release to that PPA. You can find the accepted releases at

[Versable PPA dists](http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/)

If you want to install Elementary Tweaks you can try:

[Loki Elementary tweak PPA by Felipe Escoto](https://launchpad.net/~philip.scott/+archive/ubuntu/elementary-tweaks)